# How do I find out the index in a MySQL table

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm programming in PHP5 & MySQL5 and I'd like to know how to figure out the index of an entry.
To be clear, here's an example:
I have 500 users in a table, I want to select the user johndoe and the index of that user, so if johndoe is the 100th user in my table, I want to be able to select the information for him in a similar way to this:

```
SELECT *, INDEX_OF(id) FROM users WHERE username='johndoe';
```

So I'd get the details about the user back (name, username, id, index etc...)
Please note this is different than the ID of the user.

How would I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `INDEX_OF(id)` supposed to return?  Please provide example output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the _rowid special column, but it is just the same as an "unsigned int auto_increment primary 
key", i.e. what you would normally call "id".

SQL has no requirements on order of the rows *searched*, only on returned rows. That means you can't count on that entry being at the 100th position for every search. So in that sense, any attempt to find the physical position of the row, could possibly return a different result each time.

Comment: @yuval - it may not be what you're looking for, but it's the right answer.  There is no "order" to the rows stored on disk, thus there is no "index" in the sense that you're using it.  You can't figure out an index like that because there simply isn't one.